# How does python assert works on strings (which is number)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two variables a and b both are type string. It still works with greater than and less than operation with the assert. Shouldn’t it suppose to throw a Syntax error?

```
In [34]: a = '1'                                                                                    

In [35]: b='2'                                                                                      

In [36]: type(a)                                                                                    
Out[36]: str

In [37]: assert a<b   #This works like integer or float                                             

In [38]: assert a>b                                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-e1202bf94274> in <module>
----> 1 assert a>b

AssertionError:
```

Here is second example, which is completely non-numeric string, still it works. How?

```
In [49]: a='bob'                                                                                    

In [50]: b='cat'                                                                                    

In [51]: assert a>b                                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-e1606bf94274> in <module>
----> 1 assert a>b

AssertionError: 

In [52]: assert a<b     # How does this becomes true?
```

Comment: ASCII value comparisons. The characters of 'bob' have a lower value than 'cat'. Same for '1' and '2'.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. `a = '1'; b = '2'` are still strings no numbers. Python does something like `ord('1') > ord('2')`. So `'2' > '10'` is True because `ord('2') > ord('1')`.

Answer (score 1):

when you evaluate `'bob'   >  'cat'`  will actually evaluate the elements from left to right, first will compare character `'b'` with '`c`' which is obvious that '`b`'  is not > than `'c'` (you could use the built-in function `ord` to check the  value) since they are not equal the evaluation will stop and the truth value of the expression is `False` so your line `assert a>b` will raise `AssertionError`

Comment: That make sense. I wasn't looking at ASCII values.